# Find kind of TypeReference using TypeScript API

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to find the kind (class, interface, type alias, enumeration ...) of a `TypeReference`.

I have this:

```
const anode = node as ts.TypeReferenceNode;
const symbol = this.typechecker.getSymbolAtLocation(anode.typeName) as ts.Symbol;
const type = this.typechecker.getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(symbol, anode);
const decls = symbol.getDeclarations() as ts.Declaration[];
```

**But the call to `getSymbolAtLocation` returns `undefined`.**

`anode` is a `TypeReferenceNode` (kind 159) according to VSC debugger:

[image]

And escapedText `ETypes` references to an enum reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out a solution:

```
const anode = node as ts.TypeReferenceNode;
const type = this.typechecker.getTypeAtLocation(anode);
const symbol = type.symbol || type.aliasSymbol;
const decls = symbol.getDeclarations() as ts.Declaration[];
```

From the `decls` array you can find out whether the declarations are Interfaces, Classes, etc...