# How can I use the TypeScript Compiler API to extract the type of an array

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

How can I use the TypeScript Compiler API to extract the type of an array? For example given this source:

```
let a: string[] = []
```

How can I go from getting the type `string[]` to just `string`?

[ts-morph](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph/blob/f9032618bc0b7e4e12adb851a131b37804dc78fe/packages/ts-morph/src/compiler/types/Type.ts#L74) makes this easy but I haven't figured out how to replicate it with the raw TS Compiler API.

It seems that I need to use `checker.getTypeArguments()` but it wants a `ts.TypeReference` type which I don't know how to create.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test for array of string type in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130292/test-for-array-of-string-type-in-typescript)

Comment: I'm asking at the meta level, TypeScript Compiler API. Title updated accordingly.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660003/find-kind-of-typereference-using-typescript-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array type such as `string[]` will be in the form:

```
Array<string>
```

If you have one of these types, you can just assert it as a `ts.TypeReference` and pass it into `TypeChecker#getTypeArguments`:

```
const typeArgs = typeChecker.getTypeArguments(arrayType as ts.TypeReference);
const elementType = typeArgs[0];
```

To check if a type is an array type, I usually just check the type's symbol's name for `Array` and if it has a single type argument.

Comment: Thanks David, what eluded me was the type cast. Is there no other way? And how did you figure this out? Is it expected that API users should intuit usage like this or did you learn this by e.g. talking to the core team over gitter etc.?